# Android WebView can't show the right border of the html table on some phones

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WebView in my XML file as below:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

But it have a problem on some phones when it loads the website which has a 
table, it can't show the right border of the table as the pic below on some phones like MI.But it fit well on Nexus and Samsung phones.
Also it doesn't work if I hide the scrollbar in xml or user the code as below.

```
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try `<WebView android:id="@+id/myWebView"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:scrollbars="none"/>`

Comment: I have tried this ,but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

**One way**

And make true you add `@JavascriptInterface`

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

**Another way**

change to this.

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

**Edited**

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.requestFocus();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // add loadUrl
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**Add`@JavascriptInterface`**

```
@JavascriptInterface
public static void loadUrl(WebView webView, String url) {
   // do something here
}
```

You can check it.

Comment: Yeah ,I have tried both of them ,But it still not work .anyway thinks for your help.

Comment: And by the way what do you mean of add @JavascriptInterface,where I need to put this?

Comment: Yeah ,it work for adding the below code ,but it seems to load a pc website,it cant fit to the phone screen.
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"/>
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help ,this not work for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try webview with ScrollView like that.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/scroll">
      <WebView
         android:id="@+id/webView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_margin="0dp"
         android:padding="0dp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

I hope this may help you.